# Check if two numbers have same bits set

Tags: php

I have two decimal numbers. If both the bits at any identical positions are set, then comparison should return true otherwise false. For example

1. number1 = 196 = 11000100
2. number2 =  4  = 00000100
3. number3 =  16 = 00010000

=> Comparison of number1 and number2 will return true.

=> Comparison of number1 and number3 will return false.

=> Comparison of number2 and number3 will return false.

In PHP, is there any inbuilt function for this type of comparison or how can we write custom logic for it?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: I am not able to figure out the optimum logic for it.

Comment: How come `196` and `4` should return true?

Comment: Pretty unclear question indeed. You need to explain the steps as well as how do you derive something as `true` or `false`! You just need the check of `($a & $b) != 0`

Comment: @JohnPancoast's answer at the duplicate is pretty informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Bitwise Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php#language.operators.bitwise):

> **$a & $b**   And Bits that are set in both $a and $b are set.

```
var_dump(196 & 4);
var_dump(196 & 16);
var_dump(4 & 16);
```

Where `0` is `false` non-zero is `true`:

```
int(4)
int(0)
int(0)
```

You can cast to boolean `true` or `false`:

```
var_dump((bool) (196 & 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bitwise operators:

```
$number1 = 196;
$number2 = 4;

if ($number1 & $number2){
  echo "Number 1 and 2 are equal";
} else {
  echo "Number 1 and 2 are not equal";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise answer is way better than mine, but here's how to do it without using bitwise operators:

```
<?php


function hasMatchingBits($x, $y) 
{
    $x = strrev(decbin($x));
    $y = strrev(decbin($y));
    $lengthX = strlen($x);
    $lengthY = strlen($y);
    $length = $lengthX < $lengthY ? $lengthX : $lengthY;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if ($x[$i] === '1' && $y[$i] === '1') {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

echo hasMatchingBits(196, 4) ? "Yes\n" : "No\n";
echo hasMatchingBits(196, 16) ? "Yes\n" : "No\n";
echo hasMatchingBits(4, 16) ? "Yes\n" : "No\n";
```

Which you can see here https://3v4l.org/8lSJX

Comment: This was exactly what I have used earlier